# Android ExpandableListView Click Outside Items

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I have an activity with an expandableListView in it !

I would like to register to an event when someone clicks on the expandableListView, but not on a group nor an item. In other words, when there is space left under all items, i want to capture a click there.

I tried a lot of things, and the only thing that works for me is

```
    expListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(SetsActivity.this, "" + event.getY()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, this captures everything. I would like to be able to know if this is the empty space or not. Is there a way ?

Comment: Your expandablelistview is contained in a layout, why not set the onclick listener on the layout instead. The space belongs to the layout i believe.

Comment: I've tried, but it seems the space belongs to the elv, not the layout. Proof is that I currently see my toast when clicking on the empty space. I've tried setting the elv height to "wrap_content" as some listview answer suggested, but thast did not change anything